# Telerik gridview : How to refresh grid view after Database change

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, dataset, telerik-grid

I'm using `radgridview` in C# winform application to show data from database. I'm also altering database through ADO.Net. The problem is after I change the database, for example by deleting a row or adding a new row, changes do not appear in gridview.
I also want to mention that I have bound database to gridview through smart tags and when I tried to create a new dataset and assign it to `radgridview1.datasource` I got tons of errors.
Any suggestion on how can force `radgridview` to reload it's `datasource` ?

Comment: I don't think you can find anything special in code, After user presses delete button, I delete the row through ADO. that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself. Although it only works on `dataGridView` and doesn't work on `dataListView`.
To delete a record and commit changes to database :

```
radGridView1.CurrentRow.Delete();
this.yourTableAdapter.Update(yourDataSet);
```

On the other hand, if you have added new records and you want to reform the list :

```
this.yourTableAdapter.Fill(yourDataSet.yourTabel);
```

If you know how to do the same with `dataListView`, I'll be glad to hear.

Comment: Well updating the TableAdapter is just what I suggested above :). Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

When datasource get changes, to refresh datagrid use following code :

```
this.radGridViewName.MasterTemplate.Refresh(null);
```

this line solved my problem :-)

Comment: Also try `this.radGridViewName.TableElement.UpdateView();`

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple soultion to refresh data in grid:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = null;
MyGrid.DataSource = updatedData;
```

Comment: Again load it from the database.

Comment: If I create a new dataset and fill it through `adapter.Fill(ds)` I get null pointer exception in `itemDatabound` event handler.

Comment: As I said before, I didn't connect to db programmitically, I used smart tags properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-tutorial-binding-to-datatable-or-dataset.html), explaining in a step by step manner how to bind the grid. Once it is bound, changes introduced to the underlying source will be automatically reflected and changed in RadGridView will be updated in the DataTable after you Update the TableAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to Alexander's:

```
List<ClassOfDataRow> t = radGridView.ItemsSource as List<ClassOfDataRow>;
radGridView.ItemsSource = null;
radGridView.ItemsSource = t;
```

`ClassOfDataRow` is the class used to store one row of data in the grid and `radGridView` is the name of your RadGridView.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset has a clear function which can be called before new data is passed to the  dataset :

```
Resultset.Clear();
DataAdapter.fill(Resultset);
Radgridview.datasource=Resultset;
```