# Refresh GridView programmatically if new columns are created

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

So I am developing a little project in Visual Studio to learn a bit more about SQL, .NET and C#.
At the moment i have this block of code that allows me to create two new columns in a database in case the statement is met.:`

```
int year = 2018;
        Boolean runOnce = true;
        DateTime lastday = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);


if(lastday>=startDate|| lastday<=endDate|| runOnce==true)
            {
                SqlConnection dataConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iPadLoanConnectionString2"].ToString());
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd2.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE testtable2017 ADD Last_Cleaned_Filter_2018 NVARCHAR(50) ; ALTER TABLE testtable2017 ADD Last_Bulb_Replaced_2018 NVARCHAR(50)";
                cmd2.Connection = dataConnection2;
                dataConnection2.Open();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dataConnection2.Close();
                runOnce = false;
            }
```

I also have a GridView in the page that shows the columns of the specific table "testtable2017", my question is, is it possible to refresh the gridview to show the two newly created columns with some code instead of having to refresh schema?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821880/how-to-refresh-gridview-after-pressed-a-button-in-asp-net

Comment: @BongaMbombi I did, I might be wrong but that will only bind the data inserted right? Or would it also add the new columns created through the ALTER statement?

Comment: Have you tried binding the GridView's DataSource with the new data set?

Comment: @BongaMbombi No, not yet, would it be too much to ask for a brief explanation? Few things I still struggle with

Comment: Please read more from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606911/telerik-gridview-how-to-refresh-grid-view-after-database-change

Comment: @BongaMbombi just had a look and tried it and does not work